# how can i add a field in a form of a model from another distinct model in angular?

Tags: html, angular, model, datalist

i have a datalist that i want to choose from it an object and add it in another object :

this is the first model :

```
export class missionnaire {    
    cin : String ;      
    graade :grade;  
    constructor(cin? : String ,graade ?:grade) {
        this.graade= new grade() ;   
    }; 
}
```

and this is the other model :

```
export class grade {
    constructor(public code? : String ,
        public liba? : String , 
        public libfr?  :String ) {} 
}
```

and in the " missionaire.html" i have :

```html
 <form [formGroup]="missionnaireF">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
           <label> grade </label>
           <input type = "text" class="form-control" id="search3" name="search3" list="list3" formControlName="graade" >
           <datalist id="list3">
           <option *ngFor="let grade of grades" data-value="grade" [value]="grade.liba">
           </datalist>
           </div>
   
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label >cin </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="cin" name="cin"  maxlength="8">
   </div>
</form>
```

and this is the json post request that works just fine in the back :

```
{
        "cin": 88663344,
        "grade": {
            "idgrade": 1,
            "libGradeAr": "grade",
            "libGradeFr": "grade",
            "codeGrade": 1
        }
}
```

Comment: When asking questions, please post relevant code into the question and not as links to images, this just makes it a lot harder for people to help :)

Comment: okay , i guess you are right , i'll just delete this one and ask again !

Comment: You dont need to delete it, at the bottom of the question is an Edit button, so you can just modify this one :)

Comment: data-value="grade" . You missed closing quotes.

Comment: @jason oh i wish it was that but  i only missed them writting this code here

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: the thing is when adding a new missionaire , i can't add a grade , i can only add the cin input

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Grade {
    idgrade?: number;
    libGradeAr?: string;
    libGradeFr?: string;
    codeGrade?: number;
}
class Missionnaire {  
    grade: Grade;
    constructor(grade?: Grade, public cin?: number) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
let obj = {
        "cin": 88663344,
        "grade": {
            "idgrade": 1,
            "libGradeAr": "grade",
            "libGradeFr": "grade",
            "codeGrade": 1
        }
}
let grd: Grade = obj.grade;
console.log(grd)
let x = new Missionnaire(grd, obj.cin);
console.log(x)
```

I am assuming this is what you want to do. You can change Grade to an interface instead of Class (You can use Grade as Base Class & Missionaire as Super Class). And the rest is just straightforward.